# What do cartocss attachments along filters mean?

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, filter, cartocss

I'm exploring openstreetmap-carto style and I wonder what does such syntax mean:

```
  [natural = 'water']::natural,
  [landuse = 'reservoir']::landuse,
  [waterway = 'riverbank']::waterway
```

Is this declaring multiple attachments at once, or is it redirecting filters somehow? 
I'm clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that syntax is declaring multiple attachments. This works for waterways because they are all the same colour, no layering is involved, so [ordering does not matter](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/symbol-drawing-order/#attachment-ordering).

Without the attachments, this turns into a combinatorial explosion, which is a [fundamental problem with carto](https://github.com/mapbox/carto/issues/20).

This technique cannot be used for layers like the landcover layer, where ordering *does* matter, hence a [truly horrific SQL statement](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/555c8689a232394cf2e4cd060c03d285a9cee7ca/project.yaml#L103-L130).

Andy Allan's [State of the Map US 2013](http://vimeopro.com/openstreetmapus/state-of-the-map-us-2013/video/68093876) talk has some more information about this approach, and the drawbacks to each way.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I kinda got it now. But if multiple attachements break ordering (and I still guess what is the drawing order in such cases) then why SQL query has this: `ORDER BY z_order, way_area DESC` ? Maybe this isn't quite related to the question, but the same query has `way_area/(!pixel_width!*!pixel_height!)` and Tilemill returns a "Division by zero" error when creating a new layer. Are Mapnik tokens allowed here?